# Python - why mock patch decorator does not pass the mocked object to the test function when `new` argument is not DEFAULT

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

in Python 3.6, I use `unittest.mock.patch` to patch a function like this:

```
class SampleTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('some_module.f')
    def test_f(self, mocked_f):
        f()
        mocked_f.assert_called()
```

This passes a `mock.MagicMock()` as `mocked_f` and everything works fine. However, when I want to use a custom mock object instead of the default `mock.MagicMock()` using `new` argument, the patch decorator does not pass the mocked object to the `test_f` method. Running this code will raise a `TypeError`:

```
class SampleTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('some_module.f', new=lambda: 8)
    def test_f(self, mocked_f):
        f()
        mocked_f.assert_called()
```

```
TypeError: test_f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mocked_f'
```

My question is: why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> If `patch()` is used as a decorator **and *new* is omitted**, the created mock is passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function.

With `new` being used explicitly, the decorator does not pass the mocked object as a parameter (presumably because it expects you to already have a reference that you could use without needing an argument).

In this case, a workaround would be to configure the mock *after* it has been passed to your test:

```
class SampleTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('tests.f')
    def test_f(self, mocked_f):
        mocked_f.return_value = 8
        # or
        # mocked_f.side_effect = lambda: 8
        f()
        mocked_f.assert_called()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had noticed the documentation you mentioned before, but I am not convinced with this presumption. Your solution perfectly fits for my example, but there are situations where `return_value` or `side_effect` does not provide a convenient workaround. This is the blog I was reading when I encountered the problem: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/unit-testing-asyncio-code
I could update my question with the example in the blog, but it is too long.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's probably correct that the reason the mocked object is not passed to the decorated function when `new` is specified, is that you will normally already have a reference to the that object, and so don't need it passed into the decorated function.

Notice however that if you use `new_callable` instead of `new` then the mocked object **is passed to the decorated function**. This makes sense since you normally won't have a reference to the object returned from the callable.

so you can do something like the following:

```
def my_custom_mock_factory():
    my_mock = mock.Mock()
    # customisations to my_mock
    return my_mock

class SampleTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('some_module.f', new_callable=my_custom_mock_factory)
    def test_f(self, mocked_f):
        f()
        mocked_f.assert_called()
```